# How to minimize the cost for a sql database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have a website that need a database to store some user information and a blob storage to save some files.

I want to minimize the cost as much as possible so I played around in Microsoft Azure Pricing Calculator with a Azure SQL Database. For the database I think that over it's hole lifetime 2GB of storage would be enought.

I arrived to 2 options that where dirt cheap but I don't really understand what it gives me.

First is with a serverles computer for 3600 seconds (of runtime?)
[image: Serverles]

Is that time the time that my database is processing the request? For example if I have a select statement that takes 1 sec to complete I'll be left with 3599 sec for that month?
If that's the case what happens if I run out of time?

Second option is using a Hardware Type: Gen 4
[image]

but for this one I don't have any other options to configure my needs. Is this obsolete? Can I rely on it for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a very cheap one use the `Basic` or `S0`.

Keep in mind that `Basic` are very slow: try to connect to it through SSMS.

`Serverless` is for databases that you pause for 3/4 of the day. It might be the case for you but keep in mind that when you use them they will cost a lot. I don't think this will be suitable for you.

Comment: Can you provide a link to Basic / S0 db?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/azure-sql-database/single/ use Purchase model = DTU and Tier = Basic